# Manipulate the text of a lexical rule in antlr4

Tags: lexer

So I have this lexical rule for string:

> STRINGLIT:  '"' ( ('\'[\"bftrn])  | ~[\n\"] )* '"' ;

For example, with the input `"abc"`, I expect `abc,<EOF>` discarding the `"`

I read here http://www.antlr2.org/doc/lexer.html that you can use `! operator`. Then I would have:

> STRINGLIT:  '"'! ( ('\'[\"bftrn])  | ~[\n\"] )* '"'! ;

But then I can't make it work on the code.

Comment: Just get the token's text and strip the quotes yourself - after all you'll have to convert stuff like `\n` by yourself anyway. Oh, and don't expect the v2 docs to be accurate for v4. Many things have changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The v2 functionality of the `!` operator is no longer supported since v3 (you're using v4).

There is no equivalent operator in v3 or v4. The only way to strip the quotes is to do so in a listener or visitor after parsing, or embed target specific code in your lexer:

```
STRINGLIT
 : '"' ( ( '\\' [\\bftrn"] ) | ~[\\\r\n"] )* '"'
   {
     // Get all the text that this rules matched
     String matched = getText();

     // Strip the first and the last characters (the quotes)
     String matchedWithoutQuotes = matched.substring(1, matched.length() - 1);

     // possibly do some more replacements here like replace `\\n` with `\n` etc.

     // Set the new string to this token
     setText(matchedWithoutQuotes);
   }
 ;
```

Comment: Oh wow it works! But I didn't get to learn that part. Could you do some explanation on the code for me? I'd be really appreciated.

Comment: @PNguyen I added some more comments in the code: that should clear thing up, I think.

Comment: No problem @PNguyen!